# Add a specific quantity into shoppingcart

Tags: php

I have a table where It shows the product I have choosen in the database....  In this table I have an `<input type=\"text\" name=\"introduce[]\"></td>";`

```
 while($producto= $db->next()) {

        echo "<form id=\"form\" name=\"formu\"  action =\"shoppingcart.php?action=add&id=".$producto['id_producto']."\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\">";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'><input type='submit' value='PEDIR'></td>";  
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'><input type=\"text\" name=\"introduce[]\"></td>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'>".$producto['codinterno']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'>".$producto['nombreproducto']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'>".$producto['nombrecompañia']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'>".$producto['cantidad']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'>".$producto['codbarras']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

In this input I would like to put manually a quantity (a number). This quantity is POSTED to another page call shoppingcart.php where I have the following switch option.

> ```
>   <?php
>   switch($action) { 
>   case "add":
> $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]= ???????????????; 
> break; } ?>
> ```

Finally, I would like that quantity that I have introduced manually in the table to the quantity of the product in the shopping cart

Comment: In the first code, remove the `[]` from introduce. It's not an array. Then, in the second chunk of code, use `$_POST['introduce']` to get the submitted value. Your `switch($action)` should be `switch($_POST['action'])`.

Comment: You letter casing is annoying. Use proper case. Please NO UPPER CASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
  echo "<td style='font-size:20px' align='center'><input type=\"text\" name=\"introduce\"></td>";
  ...
  $action = $_GET['action'];
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  switch($action) { 
    case "add":
      $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $_POST['introduce'];
      break;
  }
```